# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - Html - Web matrix

Tags: html, webmatrix

When i open any html file in Webmatrix3 i have this mistake in down pic

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden Error when accessing website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880852/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-accessing-website)

Comment: My question in Webmatrix version 3, it's has another setting