# Error HTTP 403.14 — Forbidden in w Asp.net (.net framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

At the beginning I know that there are many similar posts, but none of them helped me .I create my first api for iOS .When I run api test in vs 2017 (IIS Express) it works.But when I try to run on the server I have an error HTTP 403.14 — Forbidden

```
HTTP 403.14 error - Forbidden
On the Web server, settings are configured so that the contents of this directory are not displayed.
Detailed information about the error
DirectoryListingModule module
ExecuteRequestHandler notification
StaticFile support
Error code 0x00000000
Requested URL http: // localhost: 50398 /
The physical path C: \ Users \ Service \ Desktop \ WEB API \ API
Anonymous login method
Anonymous login user
```

I suspect that I have not set the default page ? Only when I run in vs 2017 I see some default page .I'm not hiding that I'm new and I do not have a clue about what's going on .I used the guide when creating the api [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zzIKStODT0)and this for server restoration [link 2](https://www.slideshare.net/abhibhukan/configuring-iis-on-windows-server-2008-for-aspnet-application)

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21347424/4548398

Comment: Read the error - `On the Web server, settings are configured so that the contents of this directory are not displayed.` Instead of calling the API you tried to list the files of the root folder. What URL did you use?

Comment: Using what appears to me during the test run http://localhost:50398